# cant wrap element created twig

Tags: blocks

I made a custom menu and I want to wrap an element with parent element through a script.
element create from block-menu.html.twig
Element: `<li class="menu-item menu-item-level-1">`

my js file:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".menu-item-level-1" ).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
});
```

The console does not display any errors, the script is connected. Checked with an error. Why is the element not wrapping?

Comment: Having a div as a child on a UL is invalid HTML that might be your problem

Comment: no, my problem is that the script runs before this element is created for some reason. I created a parent through the console, but I couldn’t through JS

Comment: change to (window).load then if you think that's the case. But i'd still not recommend adding the div into a ul like that